# java -version shows earlier version but java 11 is already installed

Tags: linux

I tried to install java 11 with the command,

```
apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

install was completed, but I still got this result from java -version command

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.5 - pxa6480sr6fp5-20200111_02(SR6 FP5))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200108_436782 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 7d1059c
OMR      - d059105
IBM      - c8aee39)
JCL - 20200110_01 based on Oracle jdk8u241-b07
```

However, I got version 11 when check javac

```
$ javac -version
javac 11.0.7
```

I searched for the solutions, and tried this command below, but I didn't work well.
(It did not show any output at all and just being stopped for hours)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

How can I solve this problem? I use ubuntu mint bionic

Comment: `$ sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: It works!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `update-java-alternative` command to check and update the java versions installed on your system
To list all the installed versions :

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

To use other version as the default java version:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/new-java-version
```

The `/path/to/new-java-version` you can get from the fist command

If the command `update-java-alternatives`(the preferred way for debian based systems) is not available then use
 `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Also to change the `JAVA_HOME` you have to run : `source /etc/environment` after editing the `/etc/environment` file by appending/editing following variable

```
JAVA_HOME="/path/to/new-java-version"
```

Also make sure that if you have setup these values in .bashrc or .profile of any user, replace them with same values

```
JAVA_HOME="/path/to/new-java-version"
```

and then run `source .bashrc` or `source .profile`

You can refer to this as well https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/ which is using `update-alternatives`