# macOS tells me Java version is 11 but I just installed version 19 with Homebrew

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, apple-m1, java-19

I a M1 macOS, I am trying to install Java 18-19, so I do as suggested in [How to brew install java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601196/how-to-brew-install-java) :

```
brew install java
```

After many downloadings, I receive the following message:

```
Warning: openjdk 19.0.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 19.0.1, run:
  brew reinstall openjdk
```

So I do this reinstallation and everything seems OK.

I would think that Java (version `19.0.1`) is already installed, but if I check it as suggested at [How to brew install java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601196/how-to-brew-install-java) :

`java --version`

Then I get:

```
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

How can I solve this and get the right version?

It could be the case that the error is really simple, but I really do not know how to solve it. I referred to [How to brew install java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601196/how-to-brew-install-java) because it seems it helped a lot of users. I also tried [java -version shows earlier version but java 11 is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387930/java-version-shows-earlier-version-but-java-11-is-already-installed) and [java -version shows earlier version but java 11 is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387930/java-version-shows-earlier-version-but-java-11-is-already-installed), but for both of them (which have the same solution) zsh tells me the command does not exist.

**(EDIT) Trying to reinstall openjdk**

```
(base) name % brew reinstall openjdk
==> Fetching openjdk
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/manifests/19.0.1-1
Already downloaded: /Users/name/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c7246ceb366faabcf9dd032058533f2e54a55b52e0baf1e45630280826b0f013--openjdk-19.0.1-1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/blobs/sha256:8380eef4472205fdc0b3968c1241bfc616efaea90aef325198d767a74d2f78ee
Already downloaded: /Users/name/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f3ccacbd4108895428c5d98052e634e0bb296638d180f9fffe8018c6ef76823c--openjdk--19.0.1.monterey.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling openjdk 
==> Pouring openjdk--19.0.1.monterey.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1: 638 files, 318.6MB
==> Running `brew cleanup openjdk`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps `brew install` spits out in the terminal after installing openjdk?

Comment: I did that long time ago.. how can I know that?

Comment: Thought you "just" did install openjdk... You could simple do a `brew reinstall openjdk` and follow the steps again. That should do no harm

Comment: Just did it, it seems correctly installed and no more steps were shown :(

Comment: I just on my machine did a reinstall and it was printing the exact steps what to do. Even though my openjdk is correctly setup. This is THE line: `sudo ln -sfn $(brew --prefix)/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: I did not receive that message... I did the code you suggest and got: `ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk: No such file or directory`. Any idea?

Comment: Not really, `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` does exist on every mac. Please execute `brew reinstall openjdk` and post the COMPLETE output (in the question)

Comment: I did not know that. Just done it (see EDIT).

Comment: So just execute these steps.

Comment: Hi, I just executed the step `For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`, but got the same error `ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk: No such file or directory`. Also performed `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc ` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"` but got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251371/discussion-between-m-spiller-and-theo-deep).

Comment: This means that you **also** have Java 11 installed in some way (probably not via brew), and the order on the PATH (or for example a symlink), causes it to use choose Java 11 instead of Java 19.

Comment: Hm.. and do you know how can I change this?